# How to return to the original input swift UI .onTapGesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a function that allows me to gather an exchange rate directly from the website by fetching the API.

And I use a function below to multiply the fetched data with the Doubles.

```
        func operation(_ input: Double) -> Double {
        @State var showAlert : Bool = false
        switch self {
        case .Kazakhstan:
            if let rates = FetchData.conversionData?.rates["KZT"] {
                return (input * Double(rates))
            }else{
                //Show error Alert
                return input
            }
        case .Rubles:
            if let rates = FetchData.conversionData?.rates["RUB"] {
                return (input * Double(rates))
            }else{
                //Show error Alert
                return input
            }
        case .Usa:
            if let rates = FetchData.conversionData?.rates["USD"] {
                return (input * Double(rates))
            }else{
                //Show error Alert
                return input
            }
            
        case  .Dirhams:
            if let rates = FetchData.conversionData?.rates["AED"] {
                return (input * Double(rates))
            } else {
                //Show error Alert
                return input
            }

        }
    }
```

But currently, i have added an option of .onTapGesture that will allow me to use the function above which I have stated earlier. The only problem that i am not sure how can i return an initial value.

Below is my code to proceed with multiplication to fetched exhange rate.

```
     .onTapGesture {
                
                if monitor.isConnected == false {
                    showingAlert = true
                }
                CircleBorder.toggle()
                CurrencyLight.toggle()
                if tappedAgain == false {
                state.currentNumber = function.operation(state.currentNumber)
                    tappedAgain.toggle()
                } else {
                    
                    tappedAgain.toggle()
                }
            }
```

Kindly ignore everything above except for the code line

```
state.currentNumber = function.operation(state.currentNumber)
```

How can I return the input value which has been inputted earlier than function.operation(state.currentNumber) has been taken it placed (Initial value before .onTapGesture has been entered)?

BTW the state.currentNumber = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your `state`, but you need to store your previous number in an other variable, something like this:

```
if tappedAgain == false {
    state.storedNumber = state.currentNumber
    state.currentNumber = function.operation(state.currentNumber)
    tappedAgain.toggle()
} else {
    state.currentNumber = state.storedNumber
    tappedAgain.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for! You are amazing! I just did exactly what you have suggested to me. Thank you and it worked.